# customize start point for a Barchart with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, graph, charts

I am trying to create a bar chart using JavaFX, but I have to adjust the starting point of xAxis of Bars. As an example if a Bar can start from 5 instead of 0 and second one from 10 instead of 0.

Thank you if someone can make a suggestion. Here is an example of what I am looking for:

[image: image of desired chart]

Comment: That looks more like a Gnatt chart than a simple bar chart. JavaFX does not have a Gnatt chart implementation and I don't believe a `BarChart` can be modified to fit your needs, at least not easily. You might be able to do something with [jfreechartfx](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart-fx) though.

Comment: @Slaw : Oh, thank you very much, I thought I could do something like this with Barchart, but you're right! It is better if I try to create a Gannt diagram than Barchart! that was a big help!